# System of equations ( Modulo )

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[image]

Hello everyone. I solved this system, but I dont know how to collect the answers. So I got:

(x_1 -x_2 -x_3 = 0)
(0   -2x_2  0  = 0)
(0     0   x_3 = 0) in matrix. x_3=x_2=x_1 = 0 I got. But there is one solution. x_1 = x_3 = 1. x_2=0. But how can I see it?
Modulo 2

Comment: are you working with modulo $2$?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh sorry, yes

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Thank u! Can I ask u one question? If I want to find the Basis of this system, it will be only (1,0,1)? Because (0,0,0) is linear depend, isnt?

Answer (score 1):

From the last equation we know that $x_1=x_3$. Using this information, $x_2=0$ from the first two equations.

Hence, we reduce the system to $x_2=0$ and $x_1=x_3$.

The two solutions are $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Thank u! Can I ask u one question? If I want to find the Basis of this system, it will be only (1,0,1)? Because (0,0,0) is linear depend, isnt?

Comment: Yes. Btw, you might like to read up on Gaussian elimination.